# Attaching a Widget at a specific node

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to add a custom widget to a specific div any time I initialize a new widget.

I believe the most standard way would be to use something link

```
 (new MyFirstWidget()).placeAt('myDiv');
```

I am not really enthusiastic about this approach because it requires details for `placeAt()` at every initialization, and in my case I need to force that type of widget to be nested in specific div all the time.

Instead I would like add this information inside widget class.

At the moment I am using the followed code, using `placeAt()` in `postCreate()` works fine.

I would like to know:

1. Is `postCreate()` the right place? Can be added in a better point
   during widget life-cycle?
2. I have notice that before calling `this.placeAt()` in `postCreate()` widget is flagged as `rendered`, when actually has
   not been rendered, because has not been added to the DOM yet... why
   is that?

---

```
  define([
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dojo/dom-construct',
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
        'dojo/text!./templates/PanelBasic.html'
    ], function (
        declare,
        domConstruct,
        _WidgetBase,
        _TemplatedMixin,
        template
        ) {
        'use strict';
        var attachTo = 'myPanels';
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            templateString: template,
            ntvType: 'Panel',
            constructor: function () {
            },
            postCreate: function () {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.placeAt(attachTo);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postCreate` seems like the appropriate point in the lifecycle for this.  You probably don't want to forget to call `this.inherited(arguments)` in it first though.

The `_rendered` flag is internal to `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` and is set to true after `buildRendering` runs, which is responsible for creating DOM elements from the widget's template.  In that sense, it has been "rendered" (from template string to DOM), although it's not in document flow yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added my question mentioning this.inherited()

Comment: Just a quick question, not related, is it usual to use this.inherited(arguments) in costructor() and in this.preamble()? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: `declare` already chains constructors by default, so you shouldn't call `inherited` there (and `declare` will actually warn about it).  As far as I know, that is only specifically the case with `constructor`.

Comment: I had a look at the code for dijit._WidgetBase for method postCreate(), I have noticed that there is not implementation in that file. So may I ask you... why I should call this.inherited(arguments) in postCreate() method if is super-class has no implementation? I have noticed that this.inherited(arguments) creates some problem when by class use 'strict mode', please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208956/dojo-error-when-using-this-inheritedarguments-in-strict-mode thanks for your expertise on this.

Comment: `_WidgetBase` and `_TemplatedMixin` don't implement `postCreate`, so if you're *only* inheriting those, then sure, you don't need to call `inherited` in it.  However, various other widgets *do* implement `postCreate`, so in general as a rule of thumb it is a better idea not to forget to call `inherited` lest you accidentally clobber/break existing functionality.  Meanwhile, `declare` is inherently incompatible with strict mode because it accesses the caller chain which isn't allowed in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :). Do you know if there is a work around regarding "declare is incompatible with strict mode"? I have a related question here. Have a nice day.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208956/dojo-error-when-using-this-inheritedarguments-in-strict-mode