# TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties , Dojo error on inherited method call

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a Dojo class B that extends from another class A. When I call inherited from class B it is throwing the error.

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

pseudo code

```
class B define(["./A"],function(A) {
  return declare([A], { 

     foo: function(){
     let somevarialbe = arguments;
        when(service call here, function (response) {
          inherited(somevarialbe); //this is giving the above error
          inherited(arguments); //no error it executes the parent method
        }.bind(this));
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Instead of pseudocode, please give an [mcve] by removing parts of your actual code while maintaining reproducibility of the problem.

Comment: The code given here matches my actual code. There is an async call happening inside my function. And in the response block of the async, I am calling the inherited method.

Comment: This is a known issue and has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208956/dojo-error-when-using-this-inheritedarguments-in-strict-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOJO error when using this.inherited(arguments) in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208956/dojo-error-when-using-this-inheritedarguments-in-strict-mode)